# Basic RSA python program

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

So for a school project i am trying to make a basic encrypt/decrypt program using the RSA algorithm, this is the code i have made so far. The two problems I am experiencing is one; the actually equation carried out in the Encrypt function, isn't reversed due to the equation in the decrypt function and I'm not sure why....
My public key to be entered first is 33127 in this case and the private key to unscramble is 31272011.
The second issue is that apparently the plaintxt can't be printed at the end of decrypt function due to now being defined... As im sure you can tell and i am very new to coding so any help would be great, thank you!

```
cyphertxt=""
def Encrypt():
    PubKey =str(input("Please enter the key"))
    PubKey1= PubKey[0:1]
    PubKey2=PubKey[2:5]
    PubKey1= int(PubKey1)
    PubKey2= int(PubKey2)
    plaintxt=raw_input("Please enter what you would like to be scrambled")
    I=len(plaintxt)
    for N in range(0,I,1):
        Z = ord(plaintxt[N])
        if N == 0:
            cyphertxt=unichr((Z**PubKey1) % PubKey2)
        else:
            cyphertxt=cyphertxt + unichr((Z**PubKey1) % PubKey2)
    print(cyphertxt)
    return(cyphertxt)


def Decrypt():
    Key = str(input("Please enter the key to unscramble the message"))
    PubKey2= Key[0:4]
    PubKey2=int(PubKey2)
    PrivKey=Key[4:8]
    PrivKey=int(PrivKey)


    I=len(cyphertxt)
    for N in range(0,I,1):
            Z = ord(cyphertxt[N])
            if N == 0:
                    plaintxt=unichr((Z**PrivKey) % PubKey2)
            else:
                    plaintxt=plaintxt + unichr((Z**PrivKey) % PubKey2)
    print(plaintxt)

Encrypt()
Decrypt()
```

Comment: I had chosen 3 as my exponent and 3127 as my modulus, as a result 2011 is my private key.  I believe I had calculated this right as i had multiplied the primes 53 and 59 to get the modulus and used 3 as the exponent as it's not a factor of 3127. The private key was then calculated using the eularian algorithm

Comment: Not exactly, `PubKey2=PubKey[2:5]` is 127. You probably meant `PubKey2=PubKey[1:5]` to get 3127 during encryption

Comment: Also, you're working here with unicode strings and your decryption function depends on your ability to enter such a ciphertext. Most terminals cannot do that. So you have to think about a different way of serializing your ciphertexts.

Comment: So i have changed my code as you noted and fixed my Unboundlocal variable issue by passing my variables properly through functions! (feel like an idiot!) however the converting back still isn't working, I am sure this cant be a mathematically issue. Is it due to the fact that im using unicode strings like you said? I used Unicode strings as i found the values produced from the calculations were too high, should i perhaps use the value calculated to apply a ceaser shift and then reverse that? Or is that over complicating. Thank you so much for your help! This is driving me crazy

Comment: Why don't you use arrays to store the ciphertext for testing (`Decrypt` taking the output of `Encrypt`)? Anyway, your key pair is valid after all with `n = 3127`, `e = 3` and `d = 2011`. If arrays work, then you have to figure out another way to transmit the data which includes serialization and deserialization.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean to use arrays for x(

Comment: I mean `return [(ord(c) ** PubKey1) % PubKey2 for c in plaintxt]` during encryption and `return "".join((chr(c) ** PrivKey) % PubKey2 for c in cyphertxt)` during decryption (I've used list comprehension to make the code shorter)

Comment: Omg I've done it! The problem was with using the unichr strings, all i had to do was add str() in front of my unichr functions..... So frustrating! However i understand everything much more thank you so much for your help :)